# Is it possible to make a fired projectile follow the direction of the reticle on a ps4 joystick?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to make a game with core magic elements, and one of the spells includes firing a beam of wood that can twist and turn as it attacks the enemy. This twisting and turning are controlled by the reticle, but the projectile will move fast so the control would not be extremely easy to master. I just want to know if it is possible. The engine I'm using is Unity and the language is C#.

Comment: Please add some code and what u have tried to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically anything is possible, but you might have to cheat a little.

If it is a beam of wood, like you are creating an entire tree, I would start with a line renderer. You could give it a tree texture that repeats instead of stretches, and control the the path it takes with some code, and you would have a fairly compelling tree. If it is a 3D game, you could instantiate cylinders along the path, and it would still be moderately compelling.